# how to circle an element such as div or image around a point or mouse using jquery and CSS3 KeyFrames?

Tags: jquery, css, keyframe

all

i have a problem in trying to using jquery and css3 keyframe to move or circle an element such as div or image around a point or mouse continues, not delay time, just keep circle around.

Any solution ? please show me. thanks in advance !

Comment: Showing us the code you are trying to run would help!

Comment: i do not start to code yet, because i do not know where i should start.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  What exactly are you planning to use the CSS3 Keyframe feature for, and how do you think it will apply to your final solution?  If your goal is to make an HTML object follow the mouse, I'd simply set its regular CSS position to the mouse coordinates inside a `mousemove` event.  What do you mean by "move or circle"?  What do you mean "not delay time"?

Comment: I mean, will this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/T575v/  It is hard to tell from your description...

Comment: hi, Merlyn.
it's not why i means, sorry because my english is not good.
the issue is : given a position, how to make a image or element circle it for example : there are a circle and arrow, and i wanna make the arrow orbit in circle's line  ?  you could see flash file in this link http://www.mediafire.com/?zq251ktsr5mzjab .

Comment: @NevenHuynh: Orbit is definitely a good word to use here.  I've made an answer that assumed that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your clarifying comments:

> given a position, how to make a image or element circle it

#### CSS3 Animation

To make an animation where you rotate an element around a point smoothly and continue forever, you can use these CSS3 keyframe/animation and 2D transformation properties:

- [`animation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#the-animation-shorthand-property-) to specify timing and which keyframes to use.
- [`animation-timing-function`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-timing-function) to specify that you want a smooth animation (`linear`).
- [`@keyframes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes-) to specify exactly how to animate the element.
- [`transform-origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property) to rotate around a point other than the center of the div (some offset).
- [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property) to move the element out from the center of rotation (radius of orbit).
- [`rotate(<angle>);`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions) to specify that you want to rotate in your keyframe(s).

You will probably need to duplicate these and prefix each with `-webkit-`, `-moz-` and `-ms-` for a while until the CSS3 animation features are widely supported.

#### Specifying position in CSS/jQuery

You can use plain-old CSS to rotate an HTML element around an arbitrary point:

```
div.someClass {
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    left:350px;
}
```

If you want to continually center your animation on the mouse cursor, you'll need to use jQuery to handle the `mousemove` event on the document, and set the `left` and `top` properties of the element's CSS.

Something like:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var animated = $("#animated");
    var offsetX = 50; // Pixels to the right of the cursor
    animated.css("left", event.pageX + offsetX);
    animated.css("top", event.pageY - animated.height() / 2);
});
```

#### Docs

- [The current CSS3 animation specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)
- [The current CSS3 2D transformation specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/).
- [A basic w3schools tutorial on how to use CSS3 animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp).
- [The jQuery `.mousemove` handler method](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)
- [The jQuery `.css` setter method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

#### Code Sample

I had built a code sample to research the functions and references you'd need to build this on your own.  Since the other answer already gave you their code sample, I'll go ahead and post mine.

- http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDc/1/

I highly recommend you build this out yourself so you can learn how these things work :)

#### Browser Support

See [this page with a CSS3 Animation support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), and [this page with a CSS3 2D Transform support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

The gist is:

- It will only work in IE 10.0 and above.  It won't work in IE9
- It will work in pretty much any version of Firefox or Chrome
- It should work in Safari 4.0 and later
- It probably won't work in Opera (I'd need `-o-` Tranform tags to make it work, and the Animation support just isn't there yet)

Comment: hi, merlyn
your example quite good but you can see 360deg, a div delay for a little bit after it continues circle given point or mouse. And i wanna it keep run around given point without delay.

Comment: @NevenHuynh: What browser are you using?  It shouldn't delay.  If you don't set `animation-timing-function:linear;` or use `animation:infinite-spinning 2s infinite` *`linear`* `;` then it will slow down at the end of the rotation.  Otherwise it should be smooth...

Comment: @NevenHuynh: Ah, I messed up the property name for the `moz` and `ms` versions of `animation-timing-function.`  Try this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDc/1/ - Also, I just tried it in IE9.  It doesn't seem to work unfortunately, tho it does in IE10.  See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: i very appriciate yỏu help, your solution will be very helpful to me. I work smoothly. Because i'm a new in jquery and css3, there are a lot thing i have to absorb. Thanks again !

Comment: Really well written and informative answer. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were asking for:  http://jsfiddle.net/BZSQd/

Let me know if you have any questions :)

---

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg); }
}

div {
    border   : 1px solid #000;
    width    : 1px;
    height   : 1px;
    position : absolute;
    -webkit-animation        : spin 8s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin : 50px 50px;
}
```