# How to rotate images in circles doing jerks?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I need to make a animation like the one in the *Make people happy* section in the next web:

https://layervault.com/

But instead of making the form of an eight, I need to do a simple circle.
It's made using CSS3, but I can do it with jQuery too (I don't mind the technique if I get the desired result).

I found this code that makes a similar effect coded in jQuery:

```
var t = 0;

function moveit() {
t += 0.05;

var r = 100;
var xcenter = 100;
var ycenter = 100;
var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));

$('.rotate').animate({
    top: newTop,
    left: newLeft,
}, 1, function() {
    moveit();
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    moveit();
});
```

See it in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/810/

But as you will see, this example is doing continous loop, and I want to move the image doing jerks. I mean, stoping and starting every second.

Also I'd have be more images rotating at the same time, like in the example provided from layervault.com in the begining of this post.

Could you give me some advice or example to obtain this particular effect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their site, they're using CSS3 animations (with every appropriate vendor prefix). I used Chrome's Web console to select one of the animated elements. You'll see that they have an `animation name` property.

That name corresponds to an `@keyframes` directive in their CSS file (you'll need vendor prefixes for this as well).

There's some info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) and [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/).

Comment: Thanks for answer @lunchmeat317. I've seen this in the css of the site: `-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.59, -0.005, 0, 1)`. It sets the orbit of the animation, true? Maybe editing this property I'll be able to traze a normal circle.

Comment: @ManuelPérez It looks like that's just for the tweening of the animation. Do a search in the CSS for the `p3` animation; you'll see that it uses keyframes and specifies coordinate sets. You want to move your elements to points that correspond to a circle shape.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand... by the by, there is a way to calculate the cordinates to not put one by one? would be tedious...

Comment: @ManuelPérez It looks like you may be able to combine keyframes with rotation. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8612410/677526).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I formulated the question wrong. I mean: how I calculate the cordinates of the circle to put the top and left properties in each keyframe percentage?

Comment: Uh....well, it's math, really. For this, I'd use the unit circle (going back to trigonometry) and the trigonometric identities. This requires you to know the center of your circle, though. The alternative is trial and error in Chrome console or Firebug. For what you want to do, though, you only need eight coordinates - N, S, E, W, NW, SW, SE, SW. The cardinal coordinates should be simple enough to derive, and the secondary coordinates can likely be approximated somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a delay to get your desired effect

```
$('.rotate').delay(1000).animate({
    //rest of code
}....
```